# Explain some scala code please - beginner

Tags: scala

Reading http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf

This piece of code :

```
def While (p: => Boolean) (s: => Unit) {
  if (p) { s ; While(p)(s) }
}
```

Is given this explanation :

> The While function takes as ﬁrst parameter a test function, which
>   takes no parameters and yields a boolean value. As second parameter it
>   takes a command function which also takes no parameters and yields a
>   result of type Unit. While invokes the command function as long as the
>   test function yields true.

Where is `if (p)` evaluated to true or false ?

Should the function `s` not be declared somewhere ? There is no code for function `s` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where is `if (p)` evaluated to true or false ?

Exactly there, in that line.

`p` and `s` are **call-by-name** parameters, because of the `=>` in front of them in the parameter lists of the method `While`. Every time their name is used in the body of `While`, they are evaluated.

> Should the function `s` not be declared somewhere ? There is no code for function `s` ?

`s` is a parameter to the `While` method, just like `p`. (Why are you asking this question about `s`, but not about `p`?). Methods and functions in Scala can have multiple parameter lists. The `While` method has two parameter lists.

You call this `While` method by passing it something that evaluates to `Boolean` (the parameter `p`), and a block (the parameter `s`).

```
var i = 0
While (i < 5) {
  i = i + 1
  println(i)
}
```

In this example `p` is `i < 5`, a function that evaluates to a `Boolean`, and `s` is the block between the `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 0):

For `p` you can input *any* function with the signature `=> Boolean`, for `s` you can input any function with the signature `=> Unit`.

So `p` is the stop criterion for the while function. If your `p` function evaluates to `false` it breaks out of the `while` loop, if it is `true`, the *body* (the `s` function) is called once and the `while` function is called another time recursively with the same stop criterion (the `p` function) and body.